# Wordpress Blog Page displaying nothing

Tags: theme-development, themes

I was writing my custom blog page for wordpress

I replaced my content.php with this code

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Trevelle
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="post-details">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><time><?php the_date(); ?></time>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <a href=""><?php the_category(', '); ?></a>
        <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<div><i class="fa fa-penicil"></i>', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) : { ?>
    <div class="post-image">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="post-excerpt">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

and everything except header and was gone. I was unable to see any post and sidebars.

I replaced it back with the original which is

```
<?php
/**
 * @package GovPress
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php govpress_posted_on(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'govpress' ) ); ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'govpress' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <ul class="entry-meta-taxonomy">
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
            <?php echo get_the_category_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>'); ?>
            <?php echo get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>'); ?>
        <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>

            <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
            <li class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'govpress' ), __( '1 Comment', 'govpress' ), __( '% Comments', 'govpress' ) ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'govpress' ), '<li class="edit-link">', '</li>' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Now I am seeing only one post heading this **Hello World**

Can't see anything. I have refresh the page several times. Applied `Ctrl +F5`
cleaned cache and history and infact change the browser but no help.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, turn debug on and read what the error message say

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/abiglitt/public_html/trevelle/wp-content/themes/trevelle/template-parts/content.php on line 35

Ok This is the error I am getting while using my own code.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/abiglitt/public_html/trevelle/wp-content/themes/trevelle/template-parts/content.php on line 35

Comment: You **cannot** mix syntax, if you start with `if () :`, then you need to end with `endif`, not with a curly bracket. You also cannot use both at the same time like `if () : {` and then `} endif`

Comment: Also, while we are at it, please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), then revisit your other posts and leave feedback as described in the link

Comment: sure. How do I mark your comment as a answer?

Comment: My pleasure. Unfortunately that only works for answers, not comments. Feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer as solution ;-)

Comment: Done. I have given you a credit

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [@PieterGoosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen)

> You cannot mix syntax, if you start with if () :, then you need to end with endif, not with a curly bracket. You also cannot use both at the same time like if () : { and then } endif

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div class="post-details">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><time><?php the_date(); ?></time>
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <a href=""><?php the_category(', '); ?></a>
        <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '<div><i class="fa fa-penicil"></i>', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) : { ?>
    <div class="post-image">
 <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } endif ?>

    <div class="post-excerpt">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```